# Cron script */15 but not on the hour?

Tags: cron

Im trying to setup a cron script to run roughly every 15min. This script will get deployed on a hand full of machines grabbing an update from the main server.

I would like to avoid hammering of the server and offset each machines so they all don't run @ the same time.

```
*/15 * * * *
```

That gets me my 15 min intervals but its based on the hour. Is there a way to base the 15 min interval off system boot time or something? something that would be uniquely random per machine?

I know i could manually setup the intervals but i would have to do that for every machine... too much work

Is it possible?

Thanks,

Comment: If the version of cron for your distribution supports it, you could use the `RANDOM_DELAY` environment variable.  Otherwise, something like `*/15 * * * * sleep $(expr $RANDOM \% 900); /path/to/job` could work (Iirc only `bash` and `ksh` implement the `RANDOM` environment variable), but isn't ideal.

Comment: worked like a charm! thanks Justin